# Defaulting area_code to true for number_to_phone in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, helper

I'm using `NumberHelper`'s `number_to_phone` method many times in my app. It looks like this...

```
number_to_phone(phone_number, area_code: true)
```

But there's never a place where I want the `area_code` to be `false`.  How should I have it default to true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess this is what I was looking for.

```
# application_helper.rb

def formatted_phone(number, options={area_code: true})
  number_to_phone(number, options)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this would be to write your own method that only takes a phone number argument and some options, merges the options with a default value for `:area_code`, and calls `#number_to_phone`. You could do this in `ApplicationHelper` like so:

```
# application_helper.rb

def num_to_phone(phone_number, opts={})
  opts = {area_code: true}.merge(opts)
  number_to_phone(phone_number, opts)
end
```

This way, you can just use your wrapper method without having to worry about trying to monkey patch the original one.

Comment: yeah, even `def num_to_phone(phone_number, options={area_code: true})`

Comment: no, because what you have wouldn't, for instance, let me add an extension to the output.  [`num_to_phone(phone_number, extension: 555)`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/NumberHelper.html#method-i-number_to_phone)

Comment: I've updated it to allow for other options to be passed into the custom method and merged with the default `{area_code: true}`

Comment: that's better but you're forcing that option instead of gracefully falling back to it.  the code in the pastebin is probably a bad idea and method should be given a different name rather than calling super? http://pastebin.com/4EKhJnCg

Answer (score -1):

1) You can set area_code: true through callback method like:-

```
Class Model
    before_create :set_area_code_to_true

    private
    def set_area_code_to_true
        self.area_code = true
    end
end
```

2) You can set default value of area code, when added a new attribute in table through migration like:-

```
rails g migration add_default_value_to_table

def change
    change_column :table_name, :area_code, :boolean, default: true
end
```

Comment: `number_to_phone` is primarily meant for formatting a number for display purposes.  Which is how I'm using it.  `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper`